# Django how to use distinct()

Tags: django

How to use distinct() in django

[image]

what i tried:

views.py

```
def gradescales(request):
    grade = gradeScalesSetting.objects.all().values_list('Rounding','Configuration').distinct()
    print(grade)
    return render(request, 'Homepage/gradescale.html',{"gradeScalesSetting":grade})
```

the result i got:

[image]

UPDATE this is data from my admin site

[image]

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: I just want to eliminates duplicate rows from the query result. just like in the pictures

Comment: But the result you got has no duplicate rows

Comment: `gradeScalesSetting.objects.all()` won't return duplicates,

Comment: @Gasanov yeah but all the data not display result, look at the first picture

Comment: look at my update question

Answer (score 0):

Probably the way you are using won't work. Because, you are sending a list but you are probably iterating through a queryset in template. Also, the way you are using distinct won't work. Because you are using 'Rounding','Configuration' togather, hence it will generate something like this:

```
<QuerySet [('Use Percentage Only', 'Up'), ('Use Percentage Only', 'Down'), ('Use Percentage Only', 'Half'), ...>
```

So you can try like this(without distinct):

```
grade = list(gradeScalesSetting.objects.all()) # < DB hit once

rounding = []
configuration = []

for i in grade:
   if i.Rounding not in rounding:
       rounding.append(i.Rounding)
   if i.Configuration not in configuration:
      configuration.append(i.Configuration)
return render(request, 'Homepage/gradescale.html',{"rounding":rounding, "configuration":configuration})

// in template
<select>
{% for r in rounding %}
   <option value={{r}}>{{r}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

But with distinct you might have to hit the DB twice:

```
rounding = gradeScalesSetting.objects.all().values_list('Rounding', flat=True).distinct()
configuration = gradeScalesSetting.objects.all().values_list('Configuration', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: sir how to get the id of r?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59109133/django-how-to-get-id-from-the-database-and-show-in-the-html please click this link sir