# Django how to get id from the database and show in the html

Tags: django

this is my views.py:

```
def gradescales(request):
    grade = list(gradeScalesSetting.objects.all())  # < DB hit once
    gradeScalesSettings = gradeScalesSetting.objects.all()
    rounding = []
    configuration = []

    for i in grade:
        if i.Rounding not in rounding:
            rounding.append(i.Rounding)
        if i.Configuration not in configuration:
            configuration.append(i.Configuration)
    return render(request, 'Homepage/gradescale.html', {"rounding": rounding, "configuration": configuration,"gradeScalesSetting":gradeScalesSettings})
```

i use this code because i dont want to use distinct(), but im getting trouble in getting their id.

this my template

```
<select  name="gradescale" id="gradescale" onchange="summary(this.value)"  required="required" >
{% for r in configuration %}
   <option value="{{r}}">{{r}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

this is the result:
[image]

i just want that in my  the value is the id of what list i selected

this is my database

[image]

UPDATE what ive tried

```
<select  name="gradescale" id="gradescale" onchange="summary(this.value)"  required="required" >
{% for r in configuration %}
   <option value="{{r}}">{{r.id}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

this is what its looks like

[image]

**Another Update**
this is the update views.py

```
for i in grade:
    if i.Rounding not in rounding:
        rounding.append(i)
    if i.Configuration not in configuration:
        configuration.append(i)
```

update html

```
<select  name="gradescale" id="gradescale" onchange="summary(this.value)"  required="required" >
{% for r in configuration %}
   <option value="{{r}}">{{r.id}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

what its looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you are appending to that list:

```
for i in grade:
    if i.Rounding not in rounding:
        rounding.append(i)
    if i.Configuration not in configuration:
        configuration.append(i)
```

And inside your template:

```
<select  name="gradescale" id="gradescale" onchange="summary(this.value)"  required="required" >
{% for r in configuration %}
   <option value="{{r.id}}">{{r}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: ive already done this but the result is blank, see my update question sir

Comment: You need to change how you are building the context. See updated answer.

Comment: You have put r and r.id the wrong way round in the updated template.